# Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n-1} = e^x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

We know that $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n}$. I was curious if we can interchange derivatives and sequence limits in this case, so I wanted to check if

$$\dfrac {d}{dx}\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n}$$

This of course turns to $$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n-1}$$

But I am not sure how to check it. Probably L'Hopitals rule would work but it would be nicer if there were another argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no, you can't interchange limits and derivatives. That being said, it is true that $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {x}{n} \right)^{n-1}$. The easiest proof of that is to note that if you multiply the term inside the limit by $1+\frac xn$, you get the standard limit for $e$. And, as opposed to derivatives, limits do interact nicely with products.

Comment: Ah thanks that's a nice way I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is covered by Theorem 9.18 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch9.pdf).

In case the link stops working, the required result is:

*"Suppose that $\left(f_n\right)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n : \left(a,b\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $f'_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly for some $f,g:
\left(a, b\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $\left(a, b\right)$ and $f' = g$."*

Comment: This answer will become useless if UC Davis, or the professor, decides to take down that document. Or just rename it. We strive for longevity here, and this answer is too vulnerable to so-called _link rot_ the way it is written right now.

Comment: Good point, I'll change it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Ah yes, uniform convergence of the functions is enough to guarantee you can interchange; I wonder if that's neccesary though...

Comment: I mean I'm pretty sure it's not but I've never seen the $\iff$ condition

Comment: @Ovi It's quite simple to make examples which do not converge uniformly but where the result holds. Whether there are any usable, general, sufficient and necessary conditions, I don't know.

Comment: @Arthur Ah okay thanks for the reply, good to know. I was always wondering about that

Comment: @Ovi Just to take an example: $$f_n=\cases{(x+n)^2&if $x<-n$\\0&if $-n<x<n$\\(x-n)^2&if $n\leq x$}$$ $f'_n$ doesn't converge uniformly, but it converges pointwise to the derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Arthur, it suffices to observe that

$$ \left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n-1}=\frac{\left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{n}}{\left(1+\dfrac {x}{n} \right)^{}} \to \frac{e^x}{1}=e^x$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes its True.
This limit is of $1^ \infty $ form.

Take $$ lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{x}{n})^{n-1}=L$$
Take ln on both sides:
$$ln(L)= \lim_{{n \to \infty}}(n-1) \cdot ln(1+ \frac{x}{n})$$
Approximate as:
$$ ln(L) =  \lim_{{n \to \infty}}(n-1) (1+ \frac{x}{n} -1) $$
$$ ln(L) =  \lim_{{n \to \infty}}(\frac{x \cdot (n-1)}{n}) $$
$$ln(L)=x$$
$$L=e^x$$